# Constexpr if testing one template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, if-constexpr

If I have a class that has two template parameters, is there any way to branch an if constexpr on just one of those parameters? In the following example I can test if both parameters match, but I would like a single way of matching any version of MyTemplateClass that has char as its first parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,int32_t N>
class MyTemplateClass
{

};

template<typename C>
void DoStuff(const C& myObj)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_base_of_v<MyTemplateClass<char,64>, C>) // how do I remove the hardcoded 64?
    {
        // test passed!
    }
    else
    {
        static_assert(false);
    }
}


int main()
{
    MyTemplateClass<char, 64> passesObj;
    MyTemplateClass<char, 128> shouldPassObj;
    MyTemplateClass<wchar_t, 64> failsObj;

    DoStuff(passesObj);  // passes correctly
    DoStuff(shouldPassObj); // currently fails, want to make pass
    DoStuff(failsObj); // correctly fails
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're too focused on new language features instead of old techniques. If you want a template function that only works if the type given is any instance of `MyTemplateClass` which takes as its first parameter `char`, then write that:

```
template<int32_t N>
void DoStuff(const MyTemplateClass<char, N> &myObj)
{
  // test passed!
}
```

This is standard template argument deduction, not C++17 `if constexpr` gymnastics. This will fail to be called for any type other than one generated from the `MyTemplateClass` template instantiated with `char`.

It's possible to have a more generalized solution using template parameter packs, but since all parameters in a pack must be of one kind of template parameter (type, value, or template), you wouldn't be able to mix type and value template parameters in the same pack:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void DoStuff(const SomeClass<known, params, ...Args> &myObj);
```

That would only work if the extra arguments are type parameters, not value or template parameters. You could make `Args` a value parameter pack with `auto`, but then they couldn't be types. C++ has no mechanism to make a template parameter of known kind.

Comment: And even better, it is SFINAE-friendly (the signature alone decides whether the function is viable).

Comment: Yeah, for this particular example, that would be a sensible approach, but in my actual code it's not viable. The eternal issue of trying to simplify your problem without losing the essence of it.

Answer (score 2):

If `DoStuff()` receive only `MyTemplateClass` objects, you can use template deduction

```
template <typename T, std::int32_t N>
void DoStuff (MyTemplateClass<T, N> const & myObj)
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<char, T> )
    {
        // test passed!
    }
    else
    {
        // not passed
    }
}
```

Another solution could be add a `constexpr` value in `MyTemplateClass`

```
template <typename T, std::int32_t N>
class MyTemplateClass
 { using type = T };

template<typename C>
void DoStuff(const C& myObj)
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<typename C::type, char> )
    {
        // test passed!
    }
    else
    {
        // not passed
    }
}
```

A third solution could be a custom type-trait to extract `N`

```
template <typename>
struct getT;

template <typename T, std::int32_t N>
struct getT<MyTemplateClass<T, N>
 { using type = T };


template<typename C>
void DoStuff(const C& myObj)
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<typename getT<C>::type, char> )
    {
        // test passed!
    }
    else
    {
        // not passed
    }
}
```

Comment: @NicolBolas - D'Oh! You're right. Corrected (reverted). Thanks.

Comment: `static_assert(false);` is ill-formed, no diagnostic required (and in practice all compilers diagnose)

Comment: @Barry - you're right; but I've just copied it from the OP example; removed.